# org-mode beamer toc is not displayed

Tags: emacs, org-mode, beamer

Table of contents is well dipslayed when I create a latex article with org-mode.

But when I create a latex beamer presentation it's not displayed anymore.
I looked at .tex file and `\tableofcontents` is here.
But I guess we need `section` and `subsection`to work. And the conversion to beamer change section by frametitle.

So I don't know how to display toc for beamer presentation with org-mode.

Comment: Which version of Org mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell the exporter what level of headlines correspond to frames with, for example,

```
#+OPTIONS: H:2
```

Then, your outline-level-1 headings become sections, while ol-2 become frame titles.

Comment: First thank you. Yes I can actually change frame titles level too (`#+BEAMER_FRAME_TITLE: 1`). It works but know I cannot define any block environnement all become frame.

Comment: Ok thank you I have to add another ol layer. I mean I need to be ol-3 for block environnement now.